# Failing to read JSON string in python Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am working on writing a tool that takes a yaml file as an input. The value for one of the items in yml file is a json string which will be dumped into JSON file during CI.
Here is example event1.yaml

```
---
config::config_file_path_event1: '/etc/custom/event_config.json'
config::config_event1: >
    {
    "version": 1,
    "kind": "EventConfig",
    "eventItems": [
      {
        "eventOutputFiles": [
          { 'k1': 'v1' },
          { 'k2': 'v2' }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "comment": "asdhjkashdkjashd"
}
```

Since there will be hundreds of such yaml files, I need to add pre-commit check for yaml and json validation. For yaml I used yamllint and it works. For json, I wrote a small python code.

```
      with open(each_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as yaml_file_reader:
          yaml_data = yaml.load(stream=yaml_file_reader, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
          for key, value in yaml_data.items():
            if key.startswith("config::config_event"):
              try:
                json.loads(s=value)
              except ValueError as err:
                logging.error(f"Failed to validate config from {each_file)}: {str(err)}")
          yaml_file_reader.close()
```

However, this code compains about JSON during `json.loads()` call though it is a valid JSON. Error is

```
ERROR:root:Failed to validate trust config from event1.yaml: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have spent several hours on this today w/o luck, any help would be useful.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you printed the exact contents of the variable "value"?  Or its type, or its class?  You need to know EXACTLY what's in it.  You think it's valid JSON but python doesn't agree for some reason.   What happens to the ">" sign on the same line with config_event1 (I'm not familiar with the yaml parser)?

Comment: Yes, I printed value. It's type is str. It comes out as a valid json when checked on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: Does it have any leading spaces or other characters before the opening bracket?

Comment: You also have some single quotes where JSON demands double quotes.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, there are sine leading spaces.